# How to stop an ASP.NET PostBack for a button click already managed by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, forms, button, postback

I have a form in an ASPX page with a Save button and a separate button that hides/shows some additional information. Everything works, except I don't want the separate button to issue a postback as its functionality is already handled on the client side in JavaScript.

```
<asp:LinkButton id="btnHide" runat="server" CssClass="blah"  CommandName="Hide" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#dvWP">
```

What must I do so that the button above won't cause a postback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this attribute inside your asp:LinkButton tag:

```
OnClientClick="return false;"
```